# "Then" vs "after that"

Tags: word-difference

Can I use "after that' and "then" Interchangeably in the following sentences?

1- Hey John, first clean your room, **then/after that** complete your homework.

2- He was first trained as a secretary and **then/after that** he got a job.

3- Yesterday I went to the market, **then/after that** I returned home and started cooking for my parents.

Comment: The underlying meaning is the same.

Comment: Yes meaning are same, basically **after that** is used for first time & **then** is used for second time and onwards...

Comment: I feel like sentence 2 is the only one where "after that" would work, unless you add the word "and" before "after that". But correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Daniel G. "Then" works for me as a conjunction, and "after that" doesn't. But it feels like a marginal case. Combining them, as in:

> Hey John, first clean your room, then after that complete your homework.

Would sound fine to me in conversational speech, as would "and after that," because you're introducing a conjunction.

If you change the comma to a period or semicolon, "after that" works fine. Sentence 2 is also correct, because it has the conjunction "and," but I'd like to see a comma before the conjunction.

Comment: Even though I am not the asker, thank you for the helpful explanation. But, in your writing, is ***as would "and after that,"*** correct? Doesn't it have to be ***as "and after that" would,***?

Comment: The two things that I am concerned with are the position of the comma being before the quotation mark and the order of words where the subject ***"and after that"*** is placed after ***would***.

Comment: Good question. **as "and after that" would** would be very unnatural English. In English, when you're indicating similarity with a phrase beginning with "as" + verb/auxiliary (e.g., "as is," "as was," "as would"), they tend to act as a set phrase that doesn't want to be separated. e.g.: "I'm a firefighter, as is my sister" sounds correct, but "I'm a firefighter, as my sister is," is very odd. Hope this helps, and you might consider asking it as a question, because it's a good one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great comment. Your comment is very clear and gives a very neat answer.